# for loop to append 3 different values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

How can I give the output as: Name:..., Description:..., Main Temp:... Instead of: Name:..., Name:..., Name:..., Description..., Description:..

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('#name').append('<b>Name:</b><ul>' + `<li>${name[i]}</li>` + '</ul>');
  $('#main_temp').append('<b>Main Temp: </b><ul>' + `<li>${mainTemp[i]}</li>` + '</ul>');
  $('#weather_description').append('<b>Weather Description:</b><ul>' + `<li>${description[i]}</li>` + '</ul>');
}
```

output:

```
Name:
Vancouver
Name:
Vancouver
Name:
Vancouver
Weather Description:
light rain
Weather Description:
light rain
Weather Description:
clear sky
Main Temp:
289.917
Main Temp:
286.551
Main Temp:
285.244
```

Comment: Without seeing the markup, it looks like the three blocks you are appending two are independent of each other.  If you want them to be grouped together in any sort of patter, you are going to have to change the element that is being repeated.

Comment: @user8672473 what do you mean by that?  `append()` can be given any number of tags to be appended, provided the markup is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this:

JS

```
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    text= '';
  text = '<ul>' + 
  `<li><b>Name: </b>${name[i]}</li>` +
  `<li><b>Main Temp: </b>${mainTemp[i]}</li>` +
  `<li><b>Weather Description: </b>${description[i]}</li>` +
  '</ul>';
  $('#container').append(text);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

The problem is that you are appending always to the same element.

Comment: thank you João. This is exactly what I was looking for. So, in the for loop, for me the behaviour was, first loop append to #name, #description and #main_temp. Then in the second loop, again would append to #name, #description, and #main_temp. But it was append 3 times to #name first, 3 times to #description...

Comment: Yes, thats right. You could use a workaround with classes to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template to extract the html from your logic and to better define the groupings by which your output should exist in.

```js
var names = [ 'Vancouver', 'Vancouver', 'Vancouver' ];
var description = [ 'light rain', 'light rain', 'light rain' ];
var mainTemp = [ 289.917, 286.551, 285.244 ];
var template = document.querySelector('#outputTemplate').innerHTML;
var $output = $('#output');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let $template = $(template);
  
  $template.find('.name').text(names[i]);
  $template.find('.description').text(description[i]);
  $template.find('.mainTemp').text(mainTemp[i]);
  
  $output.append($template);
}
```

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="outputTemplate">
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <b>Name:</b><ul><li class="name"></li></ul>
    </label>
    <label>
      <b>Weather Description:</b><ul><li class="description"></li></ul>
    </label>
    <label>
      <b>Main Temp:</b><ul><li class="mainTemp"></li></ul>
    </label>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: thank you Taplar for your time. I'll try also this solution. Another awesome way to do.